# how to show teaser view of my content types in search result page in drupal 7

Tags: theming, search

I have customize my teaser view of my content types. Now i want to show that teaser view in search result page also. How can i do this? If anyone can give me a example with code will great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can use [template_preprocess_search_result](http://template_preprocess_search_result) for that

   ```
   function MYTHEME_preprocess_search_result(&$vars) {
     $node = $vars['result']['node'];
     if ($node->nid) { // here you load the teaser if the result is a node
       $vars['teaser'] = node_view($node, 'teaser'); 
     }
   }
   ```
2. You can make a template file to customize the result: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search-result.tpl.php/7.x